# Unidirectional Many-to-One CascadeType.ALL

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many, openjpa, many-to-one

```
@Table(name="A")
public class A implements Serializable {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "b", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private List<B> bList;

  //getter and setters
}

@Table(name="B")
public class B implements Serializable {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
   private A a;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "c", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   private List<C> cList;

  //getter and setters
}

@Table(name="C")
public class C implements Serializable {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private B b;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "d", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   private List<D> dList;

  //getter and setters
}

@Table(name="D")
public class D implements Serializable {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private C c;

  //getter and setters
}

@Table(name="E")
public class E implements Serializable {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private C c;

  //getter and setters
}
```

A (Bidirectional B)
   ^
   |
   B (Bidirectional A and C)
   ^
   |
   C ((Bidirectional B and D) and (Unidirectional E))
^     ^
|     |
D     E

I need the datas of entity E in a year.(Therefore unidirectional connection)

Classes are connected birectional or unidirektional. I save entity A and get following Exception:

```
<openjpa-2.1.2-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1384519 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.InvalidStateException: Encountered unmanaged object "com.xxx.yyy.data.entity.C@18e0a217" in life cycle state unmanaged while cascading persistence via field "com.xxx.yyy.data.entity.E.c" during flush. However, this field does not allow cascade persist. You cannot flush unmanaged objects or graphs that have persistent associations to unmanaged objects. Suggested actions: a) Set the cascade attribute for this field to CascadeType.PERSIST or CascadeType.ALL (JPA annotations) or "persist" or "all" (JPA orm.xml), b) enable cascade-persist globally, c) manually persist the related field value prior to flushing. d) if the reference belongs to another context, allow reference to it by setting StoreContext.setAllowReferenceToSiblingContext(). FailedObject: com.xxx.yyy.data.entity.C@18e0a217
```

Comment: It might be helpful to others to translate the error message to English. Did you try any of the suggestions from the error message to fix the problem?

Comment: @mthmulders I checked/tested all options, but none of them works.  The problem only occurs when I build up an unidirectional connection between “C” and “E”.
Without this connection everything is working.

Comment: How are you getting and assigning the C that E references?  Check that it is from this EntityManager and not read from another one as the error mentions.